# Does PCI bus transactions require a routing mechanism?

Tags: bridge, pci

Does PCI require routing mechanism in those 2 cases?

1. The two devices are on the same PCI bus and aren't seperated by a bridge.
2. They aren't on the same PCI bus.

I don't think it requires a routing mechanism in first case because PCI devices all share the same PCI bus (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Routing is always needed, otherwise how do you even know what port to send out to? Bridges and being the only device on the bus are irrelevant, you have to know what port, what bus and so on to send the packets of data put on. You may only have one thing on that particular bus, but it's entirely possible to have more than one bus and sending out on every bus is inefficient.